# Can't establish connection to server

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn

I've got a VPS running CentOS 6 & I installed OpenVPN (the one with an admin interface), using 2 simple steps on their start-to wiki. I'm not sure if this is correct doing this really .. I've seen tuts for OpenVPN who don't have the admin interface, I don't really get the difference.

Anyway, I can connect & do everything from my homecomputer to the VPN. But I'm trying to give the VPN to someone I know. He is at a school facility & has to use a proxy filled in into his 'Internet LAN Options' to access the internet (altough he can access FB without that proxy, all other websites not). Whenever he connects to the VPN, he gets the 'Could not establish a connection to the server' error.

I'm not an expert in these things, any help would be appreciated. If you need config files or something, please ask.

EDIT:
To make everything clear: I'm using the OpenVPN with the Web Admin UI, so I can't make any config files for server or client.

I have tried setting the system proxy in the settings windows of the OpenVPN Client, no success. After that, I tried davidgo's method, routing the traffic using port 443. The admin ui now receives logs that the user tried to login, nothing more though. See picture link below to illustrate.

[image]

The first one is the one from the school (doesn't work), last one if from my home computer (works).

What I did following davidgo's article:

1) iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1194

2) /bin/echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

3) iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT

4) iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

5) route add -host my.ip.adr.es gw my.ip.adr.es

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be most probably found in your second paragraph - " He is at a school facility & has to use a proxy filled in into his 'Internet LAN",ie the school firewall is not allowing connections which do not go through the proxy server - and OpeVPN does not [ typically ] go through a web proxy.

You might have some traction by forcing Openvpn to try and work as if it were a web application - see http://blog.foppiano.org/2008/07/24/how-to-openvpn-over-proxy/  - I would imagine that HTTPS will work better then HTTP as the proxy has less room to interfere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found something where you can modify the OpenVPN Client to connect over a proxy. I'm gonna try that first before routing my traffic through port 443. Thanks !

Comment: Alright, check my original question, updating some things.